# Disconnect a specific user

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently using **laravel 5.4**, i get the list of **online users**, and i want from my ***admin-dashboard*** to make a ***specific user*** from my list to ***disconnect***, 
is there a way to do so ?

Comment: And here I thought HTTP was a stateless protocol and users came on grabbed what they needed and disconnected until the next request.

Comment: i didn't understand what are you talking about ? but can you please guide me through a solution or something ?

Comment: I'm just saying that without any further details on your specific system, the generic answer is that it can't be done.

Comment: euh ok but details as what ?? just tell me, beacause i think i already said all important informations, i'm using LARAVEL and i already get the list of Authenticated users, all i want is to make a specific one disconnect

Comment: How are you getting the list of authenticated users? Do you have access to the user's session id?

Comment: actually i'm using this package : [link](https://github.com/thomastkim/laravel-online-users) , i don't know how to access a specific session !

Comment: all users that have `conected` field in db equal to `1`  are online! check out my answer

Comment: That package assumes you're using a DB session driver and does return an `Activity` object for each active user. You can delete a user's session (and therefore disconnect the user) by doing `Activity::where(condition)->delete()` which will delete the row from the table, therefore destroy the session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a flag in the database, for example, to mark the user as needing to logout. Then on their next request, in say a middleware, you can do:

```
if (Auth::user()->should_logout) {
    Auth::logout();
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's a nice idea, really, but is there a way to do it instantly ? like a realtime action ?

Comment: do this with a ajax call and you have your "realtime" action

Comment: Not unless you have something setup like a websocket or the client polling via ajax continuously. If you do then you could do a `window.reload()` client side.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround to do this but I think it's 
not optimum!

In `users` table we should have a field, say `conected`, then call an ajax request every 10 seconds (example), this ajax request is checking for `connected` field and sending user id, stating that user still is online, now  when you change this field manualy, any time user click on a link or refreshes the page, they are logged out!

**update:**
@btl's idea to use `window.reload()` is good and does not need refreshing !

Comment: isn't it messy a little bit ? to make a call to a function every 10 seconds or something ?

Comment: if you want realtime , and you dont want to use  websockets, you have to call a function priodically !